# TiKz FZA (fault tree analysis) - Problem with transfer-out-gate (little fault tree on a different page)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I'm able to build a fault tree in Latex, however, I don't get how to create this transfer-out gate:

[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,circuits,calc,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US} % TiKZ Library for US Logic Circuits.
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\def\degr{${}^\circ$}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
[
tr/.style={buffer gate US,thick,draw,fill=purple!60,rotate=90,
anchor=east,minimum width=0.8cm},

label distance=3mm,  every label/.style={blue},


event/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,fill=yellow!20,text width=2cm, text centered,font=\sffamily,anchor=north},
edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black!70},
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- ++(0,-1.05cm)-| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm, growth parent anchor=south,nodes=event},
]

\node (g1) [tr] {}
                child {node (e111) {Fail to close \\ (DLe1)}}
                child {node (e112) {Leak  \\ (DLe2)}}
                child {node (e113) {Shuttle Valve \\ (SHUVe2)}};
   
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

However, I only get this:

[image]

If you can help me, I would be enormously happy!
Cheers :)

Comment: your node is rotated 90 so your anchors do not match with the style given to the `edgefromparentpath`  - have alook at the answer below if it meets the requirement

Comment: Hey! Thanks for that, it helped me a lot to understand the tikz environment better. However, I'm not able to produce my desired smybol..:( Do you have any ideas for that? :)

Comment: please see the edit below

Comment: please see the edit2 below

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!! You're amazing, thank you SO much! Awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,circuits,calc,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US} % TiKZ Library for US Logic Circuits.
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\def\degr{${}^\circ$}

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    [
    tr/.style={buffer gate US,thick,draw,fill=purple!60,
        rotate=90,
%       anchor=east,
        minimum width=0.8cm},
    label distance=3mm,  every label/.style={blue},
    event/.style={rectangle,thick,draw,fill=yellow!20,text width=2cm, text centered,font=\sffamily,
        anchor=north
    },
    edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=black!70},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.west) 
        -- 
        +(0,-5pt)
        -| (\tikzchildnode.north)},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=6cm, 
%       growth parent anchor=south,
        nodes=event},
    ]
    
    \node (g1) [tr] {}
    child {node (e111) {Fail to close \\ (DLe1)}}
    child {node (e112) {Leak  \\ (DLe2)}}
    child {node (e113) {Shuttle Valve \\ (SHUVe2)}};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit**

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,circuits,calc,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US} % TiKZ Library for US Logic Circuits.

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    [
    tr/.style={buffer gate US,thick,draw,fill=purple!60,
        rotate=90,
        inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
        minimum width=0.8cm},
    ]
        \node (g1) [tr] {};
    \draw[line width=2pt] ($(g1.south)+(-3pt,6pt)$) edge ++(0.5cm,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit2**

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,circuits,calc,arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US} % TiKZ Library for US Logic Circuits.

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    [
    tr/.style={buffer gate US,
        thick,
        draw,
        fill=purple!60,
        rotate=90,
        inner sep=0pt,
        outer sep=0pt,
        minimum width=0.8cm},
    event/.style={rectangle,
        thick,
        draw,
        fill=yellow!20,
        text width=2cm, 
        text centered,
        font=\sffamily,
        anchor=north
    },
    ]
    \node (g1) [tr] {};
    \draw[line width=2pt] ($(g1.south)+(-3pt,6pt)$) --++(0.5cm,0pt) --+(0,-1cm)
    node[below,event] (b){B};

    \node[event, left=of b] (c){C};
    \node[event, right=of b] (d){D};
    \draw[line width=2pt] ($(b.north)+(0pt,6pt)$) -|(c);
    \draw[line width=2pt] ($(b.north)+(0pt,6pt)$) -|(d);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```